# Using Git for source code management on Ubuntu Linux and Windows 7

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin

1. I have a Java codebase that was built using Eclipse Helios EE.
2. We want to setup a development environment as follows:
   a. Ubuntu Linux Git server that will house the source code repository
   b. Development will be done on Eclipse Helios under Windows 7
3. What tools do I need to install for this setup to work? Here's my list, please advise if this is complete:
   a) Git on Linux server
   b) Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 laptop
   c) Do I need any Git plugins on Eclipse? Or can Eclipse Helios inter-operate directly with the Git repository on the Ubuntu Linux server?
   d) Do I need Windows Git for any reason on the Windows 7 laptop?
4. Any pointers to tutorials or detailed instructions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm: You want to develop in Eclipse on Windows 7 and host the repository on your Ubuntu server?

Then you need on the Windows machine or any development machine:

- [Git](http://git-scm.com) itself, to use it in any way, as Git is decentral and works locally on your machine.
- Obviously Eclipse if you want to work with Eclipse, but that is not related to Git at all.
- Optionally a [Git plugin for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) if you don’t want to use the command line but rather want to access the Git functionality from within Eclipse.

On your Linux server you need:

- Git, again.
- Depending on how you want to communicate with the server, you might want some other tools, but it works fine out of the box with just SSH and Git. See also the [“Git on the Server” section](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) in the Git book.

In general, take a look at the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) for general Git help (as you seem to miss how Git exactly works).

Comment: Yes, I want to develop in Eclipse on Windows 7 and host the repository on an Ubuntu server.

Thanks for the response.